# Date converter function is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

This date converter function working fine on chrome but not on Firefox! any one can help figure out problem.

```
function converter(string) {
    var d = new Date(string);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    var hour = d.getHours();

    return d.getFullYear() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' | ' + (hour % 12) + ' ' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + (hour > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am');
}

alert(converter('2013-03-10 19:43:55'))
```

Comment: Invalid input format; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix your code:

`converter('2013-03-10T19:43:55')`

Please note the `T` between the date and the time.

Edit: The datetime string should be an ISO 8601 format. Read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is more forgiving of bad date formats, but that's technically not valid as input to `Date.parse` or `new Date`. You should make sure that it's a correctly formatted date (RFC2822 or ISO 8601), or if you want to allow more freeform input, use a library like http://www.datejs.com/

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse